# Count columns with certain values in data frame

Tags: r, count

I have the following reproducible data set called temp:

```
temp=as.data.frame(cbind(c("x3","x2","x1",NA),c("x5","x2","x1",NA),c("x2","x3","x1",NA),c("x3","x2","x1","x4"),c("x1","x2",NA,NA)))
```

I want to count the number of times the column `c("x3","x2","x1")` and all of its possible variaties, such as `c("x1","x2","x3")`, are in temp. It should therefore give the output `[2]`.
`sum(sapply(temp, function(x) all(x[!is.na(x)] %in% c("x1","x2","x3"))))` unfortunately does not give the right solution.
How could one count the number of columns with certain values in it and all of its variations?

Comment: All of the columns are length 4.. so none will equal a vector of length 3...

Comment: Why is it 2?  I can count 3

Comment: It should only count ```c("x2","x3","x1",NA)``` and ```c("x3","x2","x1",NA)``` in this example. So, ```c("x3","x2","x1","x4")``` and ```c("x1","x2",NA,NA)``` should not be seen as variations. The variations of "x3","x2","x1" only count. In other words: variations of  variations of "x3","x2","x1" where the column equals length 3 excluding NA's.

Comment: Are you looking for unique counts?

Comment: So the `c("x3","x2","x1","x4")` is not counted because of the "x4" in it? So there should always be the 3 values and 1 NA?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I updated my answer to akrun.

Comment: May be `length(table(unlist(lapply(temp, function(x) {x1 <- as.character(x[!is.na(x)]); if(all(c("x1", "x2", "x3") %in% x1)) paste(x1[x1 %in% c("x1", "x2", "x3")], collapse=", ") else NULL}))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reprex:

```r
temp <- as.data.frame(
  cbind(
    c("x3", "x2", "x1",  NA ),
    c("x5", "x2", "x1",  NA ),
    c("x2", "x3", "x1",  NA ),
    c("x3", "x2", "x1", "x4"),
    c("x1", "x2",  NA ,  NA )
  )
)
target <- c("x3", "x2", "x1")
```

Then if you want to check that the column only contains those 3 levels:

```r
sum(sapply(temp, function(x) setequal(target, levels(x))))
```

`setequal()` checks if two sets are equal regardless of order. `levels` (since you didn't set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` tells you what all is in the column.

This will do the same thing:

```r
sum(sapply(temp, function(x) setequal(target, na.omit(x))))
```

---

If you want to check that each element occurs the same number of times, try `identical()`, along with `as.character()` to turn your vectors back into characters.

```r
sum(sapply(temp, function(x) {
  identical(sort(target), sort(as.character(na.omit(x))))
}))
```

(Or just set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your original dataset and you won't have to use `as.character()` here.)

Comment: Should `c("x1", "x1", "x2", "x3")` count? That function will count it. If we say
    `temp2 <- cbind(temp, V6=c("x1", "x1", "x2", "x3"))`
    `temp2` then
    `sum(sapply(temp2, function(x) setequal(target, na.omit(x))))` gives you
    `[1] 3`.

Comment: Thank you @eac2222! I wouldn't want to steer the OP wrong. @Luuk van Gasteren check that this works properly for you.

Comment: For me ```c("x1", "x1", "x2", "x3")``` will never happen as in my research the x's are variables of a regression model. So, @Benjamin's code works.

Comment: @LuukvanGasteren thank you and please do feel free to mark my answer accepted (the check mark on the left). Good luck with your regression and your research!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Chass look if the unique values are the same:

```
  data <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("x3","x2","x1",NA),c("x5","x2","x1",NA),c("x2","x3","x1",NA),c("x3","x2","x1","x4"),c("x1","x2",NA,NA)))
  vector_pattern <- c("x3","x2","x1")

  nvect <- length(vector_pattern)
  cont <- 0
  for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
    aa <- unique(data[,i])
    aa <- aa[!is.na(aa)]


    if(all(!is.na(match(aa,vector_pattern))) & length(aa) == nvect){
      cont <- cont + 1
    }
  }
  print(cont)
```